# Regular expression oddity

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regular expression to check for valid identifiers in a script language. These start with a letter or underscore, and can be followed by 0 or more letters, underscores, digits and $ symbols. However, if I call

```
Util.IsValidIdentifier( "hello\n" );
```

it returns true. My regex is

```
const string IDENTIFIER_REGEX = @"^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_\$]*$";
```

so how does the "\n" get through?

Comment: Wut?  lawl.  You have a backslash in your second character-class.  It appears that you're trying to "escape" the "End-Of-Line" character, but what you are actually doing is allowing both Backslashes and Dollar Signs.  When within a character-class, a Dollar Sign is a Dollar Sign.  Trying to escape it just tells it you want to allow both Slashes and Dollar Signs.

Comment: Do this instead `@"^(?i)[a-z_][\w$]*$";`... (?i) means case insensitive, and \w means Word Characters, which includes A-Za-z0-9 and underscore.

Comment: That still isn't quite right: what worked was @"^(?i)[a-z_][\w$]*\z"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$` matches the end of lines. You need to use `\z` to match the end of the text, along with `RegexOptions.Multiline`. You might also want to use `\A` instead of `^` to match the beginning of the text, not of the line.

Also, you don't need to escape the `$` in the character class.

Answer (score 1):

Because $ is a valid metacharacter which means the end of the string (or the end of the line, just before the newline). From msdn:

> $: The match must occur at the end of the string or before \n at the end of the line or string.

You should escape it: `\$` (and add `\z` if you want to match the end of the string there).

Answer (score 0):

Your result is `true` with `hello\n` because you don't need to escape the `$` inside a character class, thus the backslash is matched because you have a backslash (seen as literal) inside the character class.

Try this:

```
const string IDENTIFIER_REGEX = @"^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_$]*$";
```

Since you are testing variable names that are in one line, you can use `$` as end of the string.

Comment: There is no backslash in `"hello\n"`